# pick a picture from gallery, after pic image i want to show it on different page

Tags: java, android

I got a code for pick a picture from my device gallery , code is like this i used.

```
    Intent getintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getintent.setType("image/*");

    Intent pickintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickintent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooserintent = Intent.createChooser(getintent, "Select Image");
    chooserintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickintent});
    startActivityForResult(chooserintent, SELECT_PICTURE);
    chooserintent.putExtra("data", SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Can i put a picture as a extra to send it to another intent? this is my code for 2nd page to show the picture that i choose in 1st Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showpic2);

    findViewById(R.id.imageButton); // Replace with id of your button.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap gambar = intent.getData("data");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(gambar);
}
```

I am getting error with this code, can someone help me? thanks guys !!
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please send uri of the image from one activity to another instead of whole bitmap, if problem still exists provide the code for sending the image

Comment: you added in your manifest a code which make on some device open galary or image after redirect to close page or back pageas i guess you reach   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: this is the issue generate when you write this line in manifest now you need to collect code latest to get galary or camera code Read new methods to pic image Android Developers blog

Comment: post your onActivityResult() method code

Comment: you can pic image and get path of that image after that you can get it in string after that you can post that path to your another activity by intent when you reach on second activity then you should get read intent and set tat image to your activity

Comment: @SatenderKumar thank for your helps, sorry sir but im a newbie at android can u tell me what is uri of the image? in my app, im gonna pick a pic from gallery at 1st page and show it on 2nd page, is it possible to get and send the path of the image to show it on 2nd page?

Comment: @VivekMishra on my 1st page im using Fragment, and 2 page im not yet using onActivityResult, sorry im a newbie for android

Comment: @Amitsharma thanks sir for your help, im gonna try ur advice thanks sir !

Comment: without onActivityResult() how are you even getting selected image. You are currently completely off the track with this. First read about passing data between activities and then read about choosing image from gallery

Comment: Please share the whole code @JonatanMorisson

Comment: @VivekMishra sorry sir, but i use a fragment, with a example Camera2Basic from android developer, my 1st page is showing a camera, there is a image button when i click it, it show my gallery after i pick some picture,  i just back to my 1st page which is camera and imagebutton itself.

Comment: what change will fragment do ? You will still get the result in onActivityResult(). Though you have to implement it a bit different for fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the actual image's bitmap into an intent. After coming back from gallery you will be given an `Uri`. This uri points to the selected image. To display this image on another activity, what you should do is to *only* pass that Uri to the second activity.

First Activity's `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQ_ID && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("imageUri", uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And in the second Activity's `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showpic2);

    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageUri(uri);
}
```